# How to update consul key/value store without restarting consul service

Tags: consul, consul-kv

I am new for consul service config management, Here I want to change the exiting key/value store data during runtime. The Consul running services can automatically take an updated values without restarting service.

Comment: Are you asking how to update kv store runtime? Can you make your question more clear

Comment: Yes need to change the Kv value at runtime. The updated values affected the all the service without restarting the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [http api](https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html) to update KV store. You can use [libraries](https://www.consul.io/api/libraries-and-sdks.html) supported by language of your choice to write code to update the kv store. For example if you like ruby you can use [diplomat](https://github.com/WeAreFarmGeek/diplomat/blob/master/README.md) which is very pretty straight forward to use

Comment: I got your point, My Actual problem is once i Updated kv value i got a existing kv value, once i restart a service consul i can able to got  a new updated kv values. Here I used five working services if i restarted a consul its affects other services so i need to push the kv value to all service without restart consul

Comment: How did you update value and how are checking value?

Comment: Also in what way it affects other services?can you ellaborate